# Facebook 'og:image' property should be explicitly provided, even if a value can be inferred from other tags

Tags: wordpress, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am facing problem in Facebook sharing post. When I try to share any post link of my website Facebook black image. I have also fetch data from Facebook debugger and found this error "The 'og:image' property should be explicitly provided, even if a value can be inferred from other tags."
I am using wordpress theme with default Open Graph

```
        <!--Facebook Open Graph-->
<?php if ( defined('WPSEO_VERSION') ) {}else{?>
<!--FB page title-->
<meta property="og:title" content="<?php if (! function_exists('bp_is_active') ) {if (is_single() || is_page()) {echo esc_attr(get_the_title());} else {bloginfo('name');}}else {if (is_single() || is_page() && !is_buddypress()) {echo esc_attr(get_the_title());} elseif(is_buddypress()){wp_title();} else {bloginfo('name');}} ?>" />
<!--FB description-->
<meta property="og:description" content="<?php if (is_single()) {echo substr(strip_tags($post->post_content), 0, 200); echo '...';} else {bloginfo('description');} ?>"/>
<!--FB url-->
<meta property="og:url" content="<?php if ( is_home() || is_front_page() ){echo esc_url(home_url('/'));} else{the_permalink();} ?>"/>
<!--FB image-->
<meta property="og:image" content="<?php if (is_single()) {$fbthumb = wp_get_attachment_image_src(get_post_thumbnail_id(), 'slider-three'); echo esc_url($fbthumb[0]);} else {echo esc_url(get_option('exm1_facebook_default'));}?>" />
<!--FB type-->
<meta property="og:type" content="<?php if (is_single()) { echo "article"; } else { echo "website";} ?>"/>
<!--FB site name-->
<meta property="og:site_name" content="<?php bloginfo('name'); ?>"/>
<?php } ?>
<?php wp_head(); ?>
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = 'https://connect.facebook.net/en_GB/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.10&appId=546337812226292';
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
```

When I debug on Facebook, Fabook debugger show me og.image url and I try to view image but it's look not found page. I am also using EWWW Image Optimizer plugin for image optimization. I don't know What i do now and why wordpress not showing image on default url. Please help me. Website: http://urdukhabrain.pk

Answer (score 0):

If you are look at the source of your page, you will see that `og:image` tag is missing:

```
view-source:http://urdukhabrain.pk/
```

You will need to ensure that your code correctly populates the `og:image` tags.

Check the following doc for [Using Objects](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/opengraph/using-objects).

Comment: Thanks for specification. I have already check my theme Open graph and og:image code is added but from source view it's missing. How can I add this

Comment: I have also check my single post link source. In post source og;image tag is available but when i check my single post of : view-source:http://urdukhabrain.pk/2017/11/20/urdu-news-7022  <meta property="og:image" content="http://urdukhabrain.pk/wp-content/uploads/2017/11/6b99ca84674c27f04fd45cf4d9a3bd07_L.jpg" />  my image url redirect me own page not found

Comment: You will need to check your php code that populates `og:image` to ensure that it is setting the correct image path. As long as `view-source:http://urdukhabrain.pk/` does not return this tag, the image will not render in the shared post.

Comment: For `urdukhabrain.pk/2017/11/20/urdu-news-7022`, the `og:image` URL http://urdukhabrain.pk/wp-content/uploads/2017/11/6b99ca84674c27f04fd45cf4d9a3bd07_L.jpg is invalid and it does not point to an image - Page not found. It leads to a website.

Comment: I think my image is missing on default url and generated new url like: on facebook debugger is og:image http://urdukhabrain.pk/wp-content/uploads/2017/11/6b99ca84674c27f04fd45cf4d9a3bd07_L.jpg  and on post http://urdukhabrain.pk/wp-content/uploads/2017/11/6b99ca84674c27f04fd45cf4d9a3bd07_L-830x445.x44320.jpg

Comment: The image is still not valid: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/sharing/?q=http%3A%2F%2Furdukhabrain.pk%2F2017%2F11%2F20%2Furdu-news-7022

Comment: So what is is caused on invalid URL: Any Plugin, Theme code or Wordpress code error?

Comment: I have poor command on coding, Please can you suggest me any easy way of resolving this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Here are some of my experiences:

1. Always note that the character count of an image name may be an issue. Reduce it to a 12-character name and re-test via debug: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/
2. Use image recommendations for Facebook: 1200 x 630